# How to convert time string field into "hh:mm" format?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have pandas DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
         'time': [0, 100, 200, 1400, 1500],
         'value': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
         'three': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'b']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

How want to convert `time` into `hh:mm` format to get: `00:00`, `01:00`, `02:00`, etc.

How can I do it without  `if-then`?

Comment: Is time given in minutes?

Comment: @SathyasarathiGunasekaran Probably not, if `100` shall become `01:00`. It seems it's given as "concatenate two digits for the hour and two digits for the minutes, then interpret the result as an integer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to string and perform a `zfill()` and concatenate using':'

`d['time'] = [str(a).zfill(4)[:2]+':'+str(a).zfill(4)[2:4] for a in d['time']]`